# On keypress does not fire on the first key press

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this method:

```
$(".txtB").on("keypress", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if (...)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

But it works only after the second key pressed not for the first one. After that is triggered on every key press.
Anyone have an idea what could be?

Thanks.

**Later edit:**
**It might be related to the way i use the function?**

in HTML: `onkeyup = "caseValuePercentageTwoDecimalRestriction()"`

in JS:

```
function caseValuePercentageTwoDecimalRestriction() {
    $(".caseValuePrecentageRestriction").on("keypress", function (event) {
        ...
```

??

Comment: I have to use "event.preventDefault();" if the input key is not what i want... i can't use keyup.

Comment: Can you replicate your problem in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is calling `caseValuePercentageTwoDecimalRestriction` on `keyup` event which is fired after `keypress` event.

`keyup` is called when you release the key while `keypress` is called when you press the key.

You should bind you `keypress` event handler on a `document.ready` event like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".caseValuePrecentageRestriction").on("keypress", function (event) {
        // do whatever you need
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".txtB").keyup(function (event) {
     console.log($(this).val());
});
```

To answer your question, Keypress event happens before the input change. But Keyup happens after the change. That's the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

For input fields there is one more property `input propertychange` which works on change of text by keyboard as well as of you copy from mouse. Try using it

```
$(".txtB").on("input propertychange", function(event) {
    console.log($(this).val());
    if (...)
        event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I am getting the same behaviour, on the first key press the function is not triggered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use keyup instead of key press - Try:

```
$(".txtB").keyup(function (event) {
     console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: any reason for that?

Comment: I donw want to have the key in my textbox before verification, i cant use keyup.

Answer (score 0):

Then maybe .keydown would work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

Your code have to be like this:

```
$("input").keypress(function(){
    $("span").text(i += 1);
    alert("Test key pres");
});

<input type="text">

<p>Keypresses: <span>0</span></p>
```

Hope it helps;)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you but this is not perfect solution, it is just a work around:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".txtB").on("keypress", function (event) {
    console.log($(this).val() + event.key);
  });  
});
```

Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cayayo/edit?html,js,console,output)

As other users has shared Keypress event triggers before the value of textbox changed. You should use other events if you want updated value of textbox.

Answer (score 0):

try to use change instead of keypress or keyup because it will call first :

```
$(".txtB").change(function(event){
     console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` events are fired before the new character is added to the input.

So the first `keypress event` is fired before the first character is added, while the input is still empty.

If you check this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/dtyekbho/1/) you will see an alert box even before you see value in input.

For example if you type `a` initially you will see an empty alert box, then type a different character, at that point you will see it is alerting `a`

You need to use either `keyup` or `keydown`. You can aslo use `event.preventDefault()` with `keyup` & `keydown`